# In linux, Ubuntu, LXDE - How can I run a file by its extension?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How can I run a file from the command line without the need to specify manually which program is associated with it?

In Windows' CMD.EXE I would just write the file's name, and the associated software will run and try to open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gnome-open test.png        // For gnome desktops

gvfs-open test.html        // replacing gnome-open these days.

xdg-open test.doc          // https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open
```

one of these should work.

**xdg-open should be preferred, since it's cross-desktop environment.**

Comment: xdg-open should be preferred, since it's cross-desktop environment

Comment: Yep. I have put the link to it so that he can read it himself. But I think I should mention it here too.

Comment: it is fixed now :)